# Custom Filter in Django Admin on Django 1.3 or below

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I add a custom filter to django admin (the filters that appear on the right side of a model dashboard)?  I know its easy to include a filter based on a field of that model, but what about a "calculated" field like this:

```
class NewsItem(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=4096, blank=False)
    byline_1 = models.CharField(max_length=4096, blank=True)
    dateline = models.DateTimeField(help_text=_("date/time that appears on article"))
    body_copy = models.TextField(blank=False)

    when_to_publish = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="When to publish",  blank=True, null=True)

    # HOW CAN I HAVE "is_live" as part of the admin filter?  It's a calculated state!!
    def is_live(self):
        if self.when_to_publish is not None:
            if ( self.when_to_publish < datetime.now() ):
                return """ <img alt="True" src="/media/img/admin/icon-yes.gif"/> """
        else:
            return """ <img alt="False" src="/media/img/admin/icon-no.gif"/> """      

    is_live.allow_tags = True
```

---

```
class NewsItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsItemAdminForm
    list_display = ('headline', 'id', 'is_live')
    list_filter = ('is_live')  #  how can i make this work??
```

Comment: Other people already said this feature is in the trunk (1.4 dev). Some more info: [release note](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/docs/releases/1.4.txt?rev=16144#L40) and [documentation](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/docs/ref/contrib/admin/index.txt#L604).

Comment: Here's a better link to the documentation; extending SimpleListFilter is the way to go here.  FilterSpecs are out of date.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: See [matley answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355234/) below, with a link to the official documentation.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Thanks to gpilotino for giving me the push into the right direction for implementing this.

I noticed the question's code is using a datetime to figure out when its live . So I used the DateFieldFilterSpec and subclassed it.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.admin.filterspecs import FilterSpec, ChoicesFilterSpec,DateFieldFilterSpec
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from datetime import datetime

class IsLiveFilterSpec(DateFieldFilterSpec):
    """
    Adds filtering by future and previous values in the admin
    filter sidebar. Set the is_live_filter filter in the model field attribute
    'is_live_filter'.    my_model_field.is_live_filter = True
    """

    def __init__(self, f, request, params, model, model_admin):
        super(IsLiveFilterSpec, self).__init__(f, request, params, model,
                                               model_admin)
        today = datetime.now()
        self.links = (
            (_('Any'), {}),
            (_('Yes'), {'%s__lte' % self.field.name: str(today),
                       }),
            (_('No'), {'%s__gte' % self.field.name: str(today),
                    }),

        )


    def title(self):
        return "Is Live"

# registering the filter
FilterSpec.filter_specs.insert(0, (lambda f: getattr(f, 'is_live_filter', False),
                               IsLiveFilterSpec))
```

To use you can put the above code into a filters.py, and import it in the model you want to add the filter to

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on that last part of what you do with this code?

Comment: Rosarch, the last line of code registers the is_live_filter in django, then in your models.py in the model class lets say Article, you have a field called publish_date you would call publish_date.is_live_filter

Comment: The last line *filter_specs.insert* is very important, otherwise your custom filter probably won't show up, one of the built-in filterspecs for that field type will show instead. (I didn't read the answer properly at first and was using the .register method like the built-in filterspecs use!)

Comment: NB: in Django 1.4, filterspecs (which were always an internals hack) have been refactored to ListFilter and provide a cleaner path to customization: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5833

Answer (score 23):

you have to write a custom FilterSpec (not documentend anywhere).
Look here for an example:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/

Answer (score 9):

In current django development version there is the support for custom filters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: To be a bit more specific: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Comment: @Webthusiast Feel free to edit any answer in order to improve it. In this case, I've already incorporated your more specific URL into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, unfortunately. Currently non-field items can not be used as list_filter entries.

Note that your admin class wouldn't have worked even if it was a field, as a single-item tuple needs a comma: `('is_live',)`

Comment: FWIW, a fix for #5833 is now in django trunk for django 1.4

Answer (score 3):

Just a sidenote: You can use the deafult ticks on Django admin more easily like this:

```
def is_live(self):
    if self.when_to_publish is not None:
        if ( self.when_to_publish < datetime.now() ):
            return True
    else:
        return False

is_live.boolean = True
```

Answer (score 3):

Not an optimal way (CPU-wise) but simple and will work, so I do it this way (for my small database). My Django version is 1.6.

In admin.py:

```
class IsLiveFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Live'
    parameter_name = 'islive'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('1', 'islive'),
        )
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            array = []
            for element in queryset:
                if element.is_live.__call__() == True:
                    q_array.append(element.id)
            return queryset.filter(pk__in=q_array)
```

...

```
class NewsItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsItemAdminForm
    list_display = ('headline', 'id', 'is_live')
    list_filter = (IsLiveFilter)
```

Key idea here is to access custom fields in a QuerySet via **__call__()** function.

Comment: Maybe not the most optimised way, but a straightforward and working one. It saved me headaches.

Answer (score 2):

The user supplies goods to some countries postage free. I wanted to filter those countries:

**All** - all countries, **Yes** - postage free, **No** - charged postage.

The main answer for this question did not work for me (Django 1.3) I think because there was no `field_path` parameter provided in the `__init__` method. Also it subclassed `DateFieldFilterSpec`. The `postage` field is a FloatField

```py
from django.contrib.admin.filterspecs import FilterSpec

class IsFreePostage(FilterSpec):

    def __init__(self, f, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path=None):
        super(IsFreePostage, self).__init__(f, request, params, model,
            model_admin, field_path)

        self.removes = {
            'Yes': ['postage__gt'],
            'No': ['postage__exact'],
            'All': ['postage__exact', 'postage__gt'] }

        self.links = (
            ('All', {}),
            ('Yes', {'postage__exact': 0}),
            ('No', {'postage__gt': 0}))

        if request.GET.has_key('postage__exact'):
            self.ttl = 'Yes'
        elif request.GET.has_key('postage__gt'):
            self.ttl = 'No'
        else:
            self.ttl = 'All'

    def choices(self, cl):
        for title, param_dict in self.links:
            yield {'selected': title == self.ttl,
                   'query_string': cl.get_query_string(param_dict,
                       self.removes[title]),
                   'display': title}
    def title(self):
        return 'Free Postage'

FilterSpec.filter_specs.insert(0,
    (lambda f: getattr(f, 'free_postage', False), IsFreePostage))
```

In self.links we supply dicts. used to construct HTTP query strings like `?postage__exact=0` for each of the possible filters. Filters *I think* are cumulative so if there was a previous request for 'No' and now we have a request for 'Yes' we have to remove the 
'No' query. `self.removes` specifies what needs to be removed for each query. The `choices` method constructs the query strings, says which filter has been selected and sets the displayed name of the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer and implemented the custom filter as simple as possible this might help

[Django admin date range filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113894/django-admin-date-range-filter/42115549#42115549)