# Django admin list filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add a custom model method to the admin filter, however it fails.

Example Foo:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
     number = models.IntegerField()
     def big_enough(self):
        return self.number > 99
```

now at the admin panel:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_filter = ('number', 'big_enough')
```

Fails, I get the error

ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/test/foo/
'FooAdmin.list_filter[0]' refers to field 'big_enough' that is missing from model 'Foo'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin). It's not as easy as it feels like it should be.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a model method for this purpose. `list_filter` is used to filter a django queryset, which cannot meaningfully utilize bare functions.