# Is there an elegant way to have a list_filter for a M2M field in the Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

If I have a Pizza model and a Topping model, with m2m between them, is there some quick elegant way to add to the admin list page for either of them a list filter for all pizzas which contain a certain topping / all toppings that are contained in a certain pizza?

The built-in list_filter doesn't support m2m fields so I'm looking for some workaround to allow this sort of filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own custom FilterSpec.
[Custom Filter in Django Admin on Django 1.3 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin)
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1963/
http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.5+ supports m2m fields:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,
                                        verbose_name=_("Categories"),
                                        blank=True,
                                        related_name="posts")

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['categories__title',]
```