# Django Admin: How do I filter on an integer field for a specific range of values

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

How do I create a filter in Django Admin to only display records where an integer value lies between two values? For example, if I have a model Person, which has an age attribute, and I only want to display Person records where age is between 45 and 65.

Comment: better fit to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Svisstack I don't think so; this is a programming question.

Comment: yes i know but better fir to webmasters

Comment: I completely disagree, @svisstack.  This is a pure programming question; it has nothing to do with server configuration, SEO, SMO, or design sensibilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can Filter the field some what like this by using `queryset()` Function ... I had used `SimpleListFilter`

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    filt_age = request.GET.get('parameter_name')
    return queryset.filter(
                age__range=self.age_dict[filt_age]
            )
```

And create dict in `lookups()`  and return it According to the age

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return [
        (1, '5-21'),
        (2, '22-35'),
        (3, '35-60')
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking is http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/587/ - the snippet is kinda old but works just fine after an additional minor change.

I uploaded the patched version at https://gist.github.com/1009903

Answer (score 0):

I you simply want a filtered version of the list view, that you access via a link (say in the list view), for example to view only the related items of a model, you do something like this:

```
def admin_view_receipts(self, object):
    url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:invoice_%s_changelist'%'receipt')
    params = urllib.urlencode({'invoice__id__exact': object.id})
    return '<a href="%s?%s">Receipts</a>' % (url, params)
admin_view_receipts.allow_tags = True
admin_view_receipts.short_description = 'Receipts'
```

This will take you to a list view for 'Reciepts', but only those linked to the selected Invoice.

If you want a filter that displays in the sidebar, you could [try this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1963/) or [this](http://opensource.washingtontimes.com/blog/post/coordt/2010/07/creating-alphabetical-filter-djangos-admin/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [another answer for a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355234/), I learnt that there is an [officially documented way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) to do that [since version 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). It even includes an example of filtering by date.

Still, the snippet in the [sorin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249157/) is also interesting, because it just adds django-style parameters to the URL, which is a different solution than the official documentation example.