# Django Admin: Numeric field filter

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How to create filter for numeric data in Django Admin with range inputs?

P.S. Found only this similar question, but here suggest only how to group by concrete ranges and last question activity was 2 years ago.

[Django Admin: How do I filter on an integer field for a specific range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060396/django-admin-how-do-i-filter-on-an-integer-field-for-a-specific-range-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning!** Some parts of API from django, mentioned in my answer, are considered internal and may be changed in future releases of django without any notification.

Taking that note to your mind, it is actually pretty easy to create your own filter. All you need to do is:

1. subclass `SimpleListFilter` and create some method inside that will generate your default range values and selected range values (for rendering template with your filter)
2. Set queryset method that will take parameters submitted by your filter and filter list queryset
3. create template with your filter (based on [admin/filter.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/filter.html))
4. set `template` property in your `SimpleListFilter` subclass, pointing to your filter template.

Django will pass to your template 3 parameters:

- `title` - your filter title (taken from `title` property in your class)
- `choices` - list of dicts generated by `choices` method of your class (by default it modifies list of tuples returned by `lookups` method)
- `spec` - your class instance.

From that point, you can get to any attribute or method of your class, using `spec` in template, so creation of any filter should be possible.