# restrain possible filters of list_filter to non-empty ones

Tags: django, django-admin

i have a model :

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   attribute = models.IntegerField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(user)
```

and a model admin :

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_filter = ('attribute',)
```

In the admin, i'm only displaying Foo objects of the active user but the attribute filter give me all possible attributes even the ones which don't return any objects for that user. At the end, i have a lot of different filter values, and most of them are useless for the user. How can i limit those filter values to the ones which match the user.

hope it's understandable

Cheers

**Solution :**
In the admin.py of your app put :

```
from django.contrib.admin.filterspecs import FilterSpec, ChoicesFilterSpec
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from sets import Set

class CustomChoiceFilterSpec(ChoicesFilterSpec):

    def __init__(self, f, request, params, model, model_admin):
        super(CustomChoiceFilterSpec, self).__init__(f, request, params, model,
                                                   model_admin)
    self.lookup_kwarg = '%s__attribute__exact' % f.name
    self.lookup_val = request.GET.get(self.lookup_kwarg, None)
    self.objects = list(Set([i.attribute for i in model.objects.filter(foo__user = request.user)])) # This is the magic line :) !

    def choices(self, cl):
        yield {'selected': self.lookup_val is None,
                'query_string': cl.get_query_string({}, [self.lookup_kwarg]),
                'display': ('All')}
        for val in self.objects:
            yield {'selected': smart_unicode(val) == self.lookup_val,
                    'query_string': cl.get_query_string({self.lookup_kwarg: val.attribute}),
                    'display': val.attribute}

    def title(self):
        return "Attribute"
FilterSpec.filter_specs.insert(0, (lambda f: getattr(f, 'compact_filter', False), CustomChoiceFilterSpec))
```

the last line says that this type of filter will apply only to objects which have 'compact_filter' as an attribute.

So we put in our model Foo (models.py) :

```
attribute.compact_filter = True
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? what was it? I plan to give this a shot later in the evening

Comment: You are very nice to post your solution after you figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, overriding those list_filters is not easy.

There's massive progress on writing our own list filters as you can see on this ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5833 but won't make it for 1.3.

All I can suggest is to start using  this new vocabulary: "FilterSpec" to find code snippets from various people who have been able to get their custom FilterSpecs working on SO and on the googles.

[Custom Filter in Django Admin on Django 1.3 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin)
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/

I will take this as an opportunity to mess around with FilterSpecs myself!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_filter = ['attribute_1', 'attribute_2']
```

Sets-up the filters for the admin

`list_display = ('attribute_1', 'attribute_2')`

Sets-up the attributes to show in the admin view table for your particular model.

If these have been entered correctly, I'm sure you'll have already tried re-starting the local development server and/or apache, depending on if you developing the app locally or directly on the server. Changes to your code files will only take affect after re-compliling, which happens when the file gets imported or called directly. If you haven't re-booted the server, the file may not have been re-compiled and hence the changes might not have taken place.

I'm sure you've written your model in the models file, and the filters for the admin in the admin.py file?

Comment: what is attribute_1 and attribute_2? I'm working on the server, rebooted it, put the models in models.py and filter in admin.py/Ok let's say i have 3 differents values of the field attribute (attribute_1,...). The active user only has records for attribute_1 and attribute_2. I want to display only attribute_1 and attribute_2 not attribute_3 because it's useless for the user