# Django - Costum admin filter not by field

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Filter in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin)

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def is_done(self):
        """ Returns True / False """
        ...
```

Can I create an admin filter that filters according to 'Is Done' with the options 'All', 'Yes', 'No'?

Thanks