# Django admin filter on null date

Tags: django, django-admin

The filter options on django admin for a date are:

Any date
Today
Past 7 days
This month
This year

What is the easiest way to add "None" that filters on blank dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to register your own filter - look at [Custom Filter in Django Admin on Django 1.3 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin) or http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2010/10/django-create-custom-admin-model-filter.html or lots of other places for how that's done.

Regarding your particular requirement, a snippet for an "IS NULL/IS NOT NULL" filter at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1963/

Comment: Snippet just what I needed!  Thanks.

Comment: Here's something more recent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691890/filtering-django-admin-by-null-is-not-null

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a custom filter for this purpose. It extends Django admin's default DateTimeListFilter and adds "None" and "Not None" options, which do what you think they do.

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10566/

You can then go on to use it:

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (('my_date_field', DateFieldListFilterOrNull),
                  )
```

Comment: This is a fine solution. In 1.11 it's not needed though as the options "Has Date" and "No Date" are already built in.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're looking for the `__isnull` postfix. For example:

```
>>> mymodels = MyModel.objects.filter(mydate__isnull=True)
>>> mymodels[0].mydate
(no response)
>>>
```

Comment: Is there a way of using that in the filters in the admin interface?

Comment: Oh, I understand your question now. Sorry, no, there's no way to do that.