# Django admin - Create a complex filter on User model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a field `Foo` with a `ForeignKey` that points to `User`. I need to create filter in the admin that only displays User that have at least one `Foo`. This would be easy with the development version of Django, but I am stuck with the 1.3.

I have seen [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/) how to add a custom filter using the undocumented `FilterSpec` class. My problem is that it requires to modify the `User` model. I could inherit from `User`, but I already ave a setup where additional data is put into a `Profile` model wiith a one-to.one link to `User`.

> Is there a less intrusive way to add a custom filter to the `User` model?

Comment: Wait for Django 1.4 (or run on trunk, but that's generally not a good idea), which will have custom filterspecs built-in. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Comment: We have been running django from trunk since they got i18N_urls and it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the foreign key relation backwards in an ORM query.

```
User.objects.filter(foo__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Just realized this is REALLY old.  Hope this helps someone regardless!

Comment: Thank you - it is quite old indeed. :-) Anyway, the problem was not to filter those users manually, but instead to have this available as a filter in the Django admin.

Comment: This seems in the ballpark - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin-on-django-1-3-or-below