# Django admin filter list with custom model manager extra methods

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-admin

I have an `Address` model that contains two float fields, `lat` and `lng`. I have written a custom model manager with a `nearby(lat, lng, distance)` method that uses raw SQL to return only `Address`es which lie within a certain radius. (GeoDjango appeared to be overkill).

Example call:
`Address.objects.nearby(53.3, 13.4, 10)` (returns QuerySet)

Now I want to dynamically filter `Address` objects in the Django admin using this method (ideally letting the user pick a location on a  Google map and a max distance using a slider). I have no idea how to achieve that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**CLARIFICATION**
You don't need to write any JavaScript for me, I just want to know how to make Django admin evaluate extra Query parameters in the URL, such that I can do queries like `/admin/appname/address/?lat=53&long=13&dist=10`. I can then probably figure out how to stuff a Google map and the required JavaScript magic into the template myself.

**UPDATE**
I've tried to overwrite `queryset` in the ModelAdmin like so:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    try:
        lat = float(request.REQUEST['lat'])
        lng = float(request.REQUEST['lng'])
        dist  = int(request.REQUEST['dist'])
        matches = Address.objects.nearby(lat=lat, lng=lng, dist=dist)
        return matches
    except:
        return super(ReportAdmin, self).queryset(request)
```

However, the admin does not like it and returns with `?e=1`, without filtering the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this to the ModelAdmin of the object class that has the `address` as a FK:

```
def lookup_allowed(self, lookup, *args, **kwargs):
    if lookup == 'address__dst':
        return True
    return super(ReportAdmin, self).lookup_allowed(lookup, args, **kwargs)
```

I've added this to the model

```
def _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        value = kwargs.pop('address__dst')
        matches = self.nearby(*map(float, value.split(',')))
        pks = [m.pk for m in matches]
        kwargs.update({ 'pk__in': pks })
    except:
        pass
    return super(ReportQuerySet, self)._filter_or_exclude(negate, *args, **kwargs)
```

allowing me to filter like `?address_dst=lat,lng,dst`.

Is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score -1):

If you need this functionality on admin list display page you can write a custom filter.

See the solution in: [Custom Filter in Django Admin on Django 1.3 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin).

Comment: As far as I can see, this only lets you allow to filter on existing `lookup fields`. In the example they are using `fieldname_gte` and `fieldname_lte`. The db manager extra method does not give me new lookup fields for latlong+distance.