# No module named filterspecs

Tags: django, eclipse

In eclipse,when i create new project, i got an error like,

```
       Error creating Django project     
    settings.py file not created     
    Stdout:
    Stderr:
```

If i synchronize present project and runserver, iam getting Error: No module named filterspecs.But i haven't used filterspecs in my project. Already filterspecs.py installed in usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin.

Kindly advise to rectify the error.

Answer (score 4):

You may be using `django.contrib.admin.filterspecs` to create custom filters for your admin pages, such as outlined here:
[Custom Filter in Django Admin on Django 1.3 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin)

Unfortunatelly, you will have to rewrite these using the new `list_filter` module functionality.

See the manual here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well, even though my code wasn't directly using any filterspecs.

Run `python manage.py runserver --traceback` to see exactly where the error is coming from.

This module was removed in Django 1.4, but other external modules you have listed in your settings.py might still be using it, so make sure you upgrade everything in your INSTALLED_APPS list. In my case, I was using an outdated version of FeinCMS, but after I upgraded it, the error went away.

Answer (score -5):

Obviously, your system is lacking `filterspecs` module which is required by the project. Install it by typing `sudo pip install filterspecs` in the console (if you are on linux)

Comment: Iam getting the followng msg when i try the above code. Downloading/unpacking filterspecs
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement filterspecs
No distributions at all found for filterspecs
Storing complete log in /home/pydan-4/.pip/pip.log