# How to customize admin filter in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am a newbie in Python and Django Development, I learned a lot from the easy read examples provided by the community. But recently I want to implement a customized admin filter for the admin console shipped with Django. I searched a lot and only found some out-of-date approaches to get it done. Such as:
[Custom Filter in Django Admin on Django 1.3 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991926/custom-filter-in-django-admin-on-django-1-3-or-below)

I tried to read the source code for the filters module in 'django.contrib.admin' app, but unfortunately I can hardly understand the rationale behind the codes. So I wonder whether some kind people could supply some examples or references to this issue --- How to customize admin filter in Django 1.4 ?

Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is new django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter introduced in v1.4 meet your need, and official document provide sample code and easy to read. 
search **SimpleListFilter** in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).