# django entries of author

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I need to get list of all authors and their publishes

```
{% for author in authors %}
  {{ author.name }}
  {% for publish in publishes %}
    {{ publish.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def authors_list(request):
    authors = Author.objects.all()
    publishes = Group.objects.filter(author=author)
    return render(request, 'app/authors_list.html', {'authors': authors,'publishes': publishes})
```

This way 'publishes' is not Defined.

Comment: Well, indeed you have not defined it before you use it. But this is not the right approach; you should be following the relationship between each author and its "publishes" in the template itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is right I just underlined the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a ForeignKey in Group model, You could do something like this,

```
{% for author in authors %}    
    {{ author.name }}
    {% for publish in author.group_set.all() %}
        {{ publish.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You could access the groups of your authors with the related name.

For that, you can also define a related_name for your convenience.
You could add,

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='groups')
```

in your Group model.

If you have added the related_name, then you can call the related_objects like,

```
{% for publish in author.groups.all() %}
```

in your template.

Then change your views,

```
def authors_list(request):
    authors = Author.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/authors_list.html', {'authors': authors})
```

Comment: It would much appreciated, to let me know, if there is any mistake with the answer I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `publishes` is not defined while you are trying to define `publishes`

It is misleading but the error is marked below:

```
publishes = Group.objects.filter(publishes=publishes)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

I hope it will help you find the problem.

**After your edit:**

```
publishes = Group.objects.filter(author=author)
                                        ^^^^^^
```

I think you will need to define a `@propery` for `Author`:

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770561/django-get-attributes-from-foreign-keys-class)

Comment: yeah, i know. The documentaion says that this way it call the pk. If use publishes__author it calls the only one authors. 

    publishes__author='Admin' .
Is there a way to use all authors and all their publishes?