# Django admin date range filter

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to write a customer date range field for Django admin.  This is my filter, which is very similar to the decade example provided in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) but is not working for me.  What am I doing wrong?  It just shows all records for every selection.

```
class DaysSinceAdvertFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = _('Days Since Advert')

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'last_advert'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples. The first element in each
        tuple is the coded value for the option that will
        appear in the URL query. The second element is the
        human-readable name for the option that will appear
        in the right sidebar.
        """
        return (
            ('0', _('Less than 7 days')),
            ('7', _('7-13 days')),
            ('14', _('14-20 days')),
            ('21', _('21-27 days')),
            ('28', _('28-34 days')),
            ('35', _('35+ days')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
        provided in the query string and retrievable via
        `self.value()`.
        """
        # Compare the requested value to decide how to filter the queryset.
        today = datetime.date.today()
        if self.value() == '0':
            return queryset.filter(last_advert__gte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=6))
        if self.value() == '7':
            return queryset.filter(last_advert__gte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=13),
                                   last_advert__lte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=7))
        if self.value() == '14':
            return queryset.filter(last_advert__gte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=20),
                                   last_advert__lte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=14))
        if self.value() == '21':
            return queryset.filter(last_advert__gte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=27),
                                   last_advert__lte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=21))
        if self.value() == '28':
            return queryset.filter(last_advert__gte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=34),
                                   last_advert__lte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=28))
        if self.value() == '35':
            return queryset.filter(last_advert__lte=today - datetime.timedelta(days=35))
```

last_advert is a `models.DateField`

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply `last_advert__range` 
create a dict for the your ranges same as tuple you have created in `lookups()`
Some thing like this

```
 no_of_routes_dict = {
    '7': [14, 20]}
```

and in `queryset()`

```
filt_no_of_routes=request.GET.get['para']
`last_advert__range`= no_of_routes_dict[filt_no_of_routes]
```

This might help

```
class NumberOfRoutesFilter(SimpleListFilter):
title = 'Date Range'
parameter_name = 'date-range'
date_dict = {
    '0': [0, 7],
    '7': [7, 13],
    '14': [14, 20],
    '21': [21, 27],

}

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return [
       ('0', 'Less than 7 days'),
        ('7', '7-13 days'),
        ('14', '14-20 days'),
        ('21', '21-27 days')
    ]

def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    filt_date = request.GET.get('date-range')
    if filt_date:
        return queryset.filter(
            last_advert__range=self.date_dict[filt_date]
        )
    return queryset
```

Comment: I don't understand.  last_advert is a date, not a number but presumably I can use dates instead of numbers in you lookup but how do I implement this in an admin filter?